# Impementing Vertical Scroll with horizontal swipe in Android

Tags: android, vertical-scrolling, swipe-gesture

I am trying for swiping in Android using `OnGestureListener`.I need vertical Scrolling of text if it exceeds the layout height.I need `Verical` scroll and horizontal swipe should work together.

The code is:

```
package com.example.gestures;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Gestures extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
GestureDetector gDetector;TextView tv;
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gestures);
        gDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gestures, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onDown","In OnDown");
        return true;

    }

    public void rightToLeft() {

        //tv.setText("There are subclasses of LayoutParams for different subclasses of ViewGroup. For example, AbsoluteLayout has its own subclass of LayoutParams which adds an X and Y value.");
    tv.setText("ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssALGIERS (Reuters) - Algerian President Abdelaziz Bouteflika, who suffered a stroke last year, has been in a Paris hospital since Monday for a long-planned check-up and he is making steady progress, the state news agency APS said on Tuesday.Algerians vote for a new president in April. Bouteflika, 76, has yet to announce whether he will run again after more than 10 years at the helm of the major North African oil producer.To complete his health assessment, started in Algiers, and under a routine medical control ... planned since June 2013, the President of the Republic Abdelaziz Bouteflika is staying at Val-de-Grace hospital, it said. The president's health is improving certainly and progressively.APS, citing a presidential statement, said Bouteflika would remain at the hospital until Friday.A veteran of Algeria's independence war against France, Bouteflika suffered a stroke in early 2013, forcing him to be rushed to hospital in France. He returned to Algeria in July to convalesce and has made only a few public appearances recently.");
    }
    public void lefttoRight() {
        tv.setText("leftToRight LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out. See ViewGroup Layout Attributes for a list of all child view attributes that this class supports. ");
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        /*if(start.getRawX() < finish.getRawX())
        {
            Log.d("onFling","in inFling");
        }
        else if(start.getRawX()>finish.getRawX())
        {
            Log.d("onFLing","in onFling");
        }*/
        if (Math.abs(start.getY() - finish.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
            return false;
        // right to left swipe

        if(start.getX() - finish.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

        lefttoRight();

        }  
        else if (finish.getX() - start.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
     rightToLeft();
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onLongPress","in onlongpress");
    }



    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onShowPress","in onShowPress");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onSingleTapup","in onsingletapup");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
            float arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Xml is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Gestures" >



    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The issue is sometimes scroll is working and swipe is not working fine.Please let me know how to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.
When I tried dispatchTouchEvent it's working for Activity but  when I tried adding TouchListener to part of the screen the scroll is not working.The Code is:

```
package com.example.testswipe;





import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;





import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestSwipe extends Activity {
RelativeLayout rel;TextView tv;
int wwidth,topheight;ScrollView scrollView;
GestureDetector gestureDetector ;

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
RelativeLayout relLayout,firstrel;LinearLayout linearLayout,linLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sec);
        rel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel);




        final LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.setLayoutParams(params);
        relLayout=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_one, null);
        firstrel=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_test_swipe, null);
        tv=(TextView)relLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // scrollView=(ScrollView)relLayout.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

        linLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);

        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)relLayout.findViewById(R.id.linlayouts);

            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            System.out.println("Density is"+displaymetrics.densityDpi);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Density is"+displaymetrics.densityDpi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
             wwidth= displaymetrics.widthPixels;
            System.out.println("Heightis"+height);
            System.out.println("Width is"+wwidth);
        //  int changedheight=(int) (0.1*height);
        //  int remainedheight=height-changedheight;
             topheight=(int) (0.2*height);
            int bottomheight=height-topheight;
        //LinearLayout rl=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate

            linLayout.addView(firstrel,wwidth,topheight);

            linLayout.addView(relLayout, wwidth,bottomheight);
            OnSwipeTouchListener swp=new OnSwipeTouchListener();

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(swp.new GestureListener());


            linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(swp);



    }









    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }









    public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {


    //  GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
          return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        }
        private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

            private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;


            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                onTouch(e);
                return true;
            }



            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return false;}



            public void rightToLeft() {

                //tv.setText("There are subclasses of LayoutParams for different subclasses of ViewGroup. For example, AbsoluteLayout has its own subclass of LayoutParams which adds an X and Y value.");
            tv.setText("ALGIERS (Reuters) - Algerian President Abdelaziz Bouteflika, who suffered a stroke last year, has been in a Paris hospital since Monday for a long-planned check-up and he is making steady progress, the state news agency APS said on Tuesday.Algerians vote for a new president in April. Bouteflika, 76, has yet to announce whether he will run again after more than 10 years at the helm of the major North African oil producer.To complete his health assessment, started in Algiers, and under a routine medical control ... planned since June 2013, the President of the Republic Abdelaziz Bouteflika is staying at Val-de-Grace hospital, it said. The president's health is improving certainly and progressively.APS, citing a presidential statement, said Bouteflika would remain at the hospital until Friday.A veteran of Algeria's independence war against France, Bouteflika suffered a stroke in early 2013, forcing him to be rushed to hospital in France. He returned to Algeria in July to convalesce and has made only a few public appearances recently.");
            }
            public void lefttoRight() {
                tv.setText("leftToRight LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out. See ViewGroup Layout Attributes for a list of all child view attributes that this class supports. ");
                }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX, float velocityY) {


            System.out.println("in onswipetouch nFling()");
            if (Math.abs(start.getY() - finish.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                 return false;
             // right to left swipe

             if(start.getX() - finish.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                lefttoRight();

             }  
             else if (finish.getX() - start.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
          rightToLeft();
                }

            return true;
        }


        }
        public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_swipe, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And the xml file is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    tools:context=".TestSwipe" >


     <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linlayouts" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="@string/hello_world"
         />


   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>














</RelativeLayout>
```

In this The scroll is not working.Please help me.

Comment: What do you want to horizontally swipe to?

Comment: When I swipe horizontally the text in TextView should change and if it exceeds the layout height then it should be scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following code into your Activity. With this code, the `Activity` gives the `GestureDetector` a chance to see the touch event.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    return gDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

EDIT: You said you wanted an example of this working with LinearLayout.

```
package com.brianattwell.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
    GestureDetector gDetector;TextView tv;
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return gDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu., menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onDown","In OnDown");
        return true;

    }

    public void rightToLeft() {

        //tv.setText("There are subclasses of LayoutParams for different subclasses of ViewGroup. For example, AbsoluteLayout has its own subclass of LayoutParams which adds an X and Y value.");
        tv.setText("ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssALGIERS (Reuters) - Algerian President Abdelaziz Bouteflika, who suffered a stroke last year, has been in a Paris hospital since Monday for a long-planned check-up and he is making steady progress, the state news agency APS said on Tuesday.Algerians vote for a new president in April. Bouteflika, 76, has yet to announce whether he will run again after more than 10 years at the helm of the major North African oil producer.To complete his health assessment, started in Algiers, and under a routine medical control ... planned since June 2013, the President of the Republic Abdelaziz Bouteflika is staying at Val-de-Grace hospital, it said. The president's health is improving certainly and progressively.APS, citing a presidential statement, said Bouteflika would remain at the hospital until Friday.A veteran of Algeria's independence war against France, Bouteflika suffered a stroke in early 2013, forcing him to be rushed to hospital in France. He returned to Algeria in July to convalesce and has made only a few public appearances recentlsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssALGIERS (Reuters) - Algerian President Abdelaziz Bouteflika, who suffered a stroke last year, has been in a Paris hospital since Monday for a long-planned check-up and he is making steady progress, the state news agency APS said on Tuesday.Algerians vote for a new president in April. Bouteflika, 76, has yet to announce whether he will run again after more than 10 years at the helm of the major North African oil producer.To complete his health assessment, started in Algiers, and under a routine medical control ... planned since June 2013, the President of the Republic Abdelaziz Bouteflika is staying at Val-de-Grace hospital, it said. The president's health is improving certainly and progressively.APS, citing a presidential statement, said Bouteflika would remain at the hospital until Friday.A veteran of Algeria's independence war against France, Bouteflika suffered a stroke in early 2013, forcing him to be rushed to hospital in France. He returned to Algeria in July to convalesce and has made only a few public appearances recentlsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssALGIERS (Reuters) - Algerian President Abdelaziz Bouteflika, who suffered a stroke last year, has been in a Paris hospital since Monday for a long-planned check-up and he is making steady progress, the state news agency APS said on Tuesday.Algerians vote for a new president in April. Bouteflika, 76, has yet to announce whether he will run again after more than 10 years at the helm of the major North African oil producer.To complete his health assessment, started in Algiers, and under a routine medical control ... planned since June 2013, the President of the Republic Abdelaziz Bouteflika is staying at Val-de-Grace hospital, it said. The president's health is improving certainly and progressively.APS, citing a presidential statement, said Bouteflika would remain at the hospital until Friday.A veteran of Algeria's independence war against France, Bouteflika suffered a stroke in early 2013, forcing him to be rushed to hospital in France. He returned to Algeria in July to convalesce and has made only a few public appearances recently.");
    }
    public void lefttoRight() {
        tv.setText("leftToRight LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out. See ViewGroup Layout Attributes for a list of all child view attributes that this class supportsght LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out. See ViewGroup Layout Attributes for a list of all child view attributes that this class supportsght LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out. See ViewGroup Layout Attributes for a list of all child view attributes that this class supports. ");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        /*if(start.getRawX() < finish.getRawX())
        {
            Log.d("onFling","in inFling");
        }
        else if(start.getRawX()>finish.getRawX())
        {
            Log.d("onFLing","in onFling");
        }*/
        if (Math.abs(start.getY() - finish.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
            return false;
        // right to left swipe

        if(start.getX() - finish.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

            lefttoRight();

        }
        else if (finish.getX() - start.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            rightToLeft();
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onLongPress","in onlongpress");
    }



    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onShowPress","in onShowPress");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onSingleTapup","in onsingletapup");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
                            float arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Gestures" >



    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks It worked for Activity but I tried to add the TouchListener to linearlayout There Scrolling is not working.Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. I don't think it should make a difference. Let me check.

Comment: Thanks It worked for Activity but I implemented TouchListener in a class(OnSwipeTouchListener).I tried to add the TouchListener to linearlayout(OnSwipeTouchListener swp=new OnSwipeTouchListener();
    
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(swp.new GestureListener());linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(swp); There Scrolling is not working.Please help me.

Comment: I just pasted a modification of your code that works, with a LinearLayout.

Comment: The swipe should work for part of the screen so I took a linearlayout inside ScrollView and added the TouchListener to linearlayout.Could you please provide your mail id.I will post the code.

Comment: Please help me.I am stucked here.